# Is the force experienced by a particle influenced by its distance to the focus of the force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

Is the force experienced by a particle influenced by its distance to the focus of the force?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: First, how does the acceleration at those two points compare?

Comment: Yes the distance is important. Assume that the rope is not straight as you described, but twisted in a spiral. So, first of all the force will untwist the spiral, close to the point on which the force acts. The same in your case, the force acts first on the region close to it.

Comment: @Sofia assuming a rigid material and stretched rope, what you are saying is *not* the case (at least negligible). This problem is not about elasticity but about Newton's laws, and I believe the above may be assumed.

Comment: @Steeven I assume **only** what is written in the question. I don't see a rigid and stretched rope mentioned there. If the rope were rigid I don't see the meaning of the question. About twisted rope that I give *as an example - not as an assumption*, it is for better illustrating the case. With a straight rope is less obvious.

Comment: There will be a compression wave in the rope,unless there is a loss of energy and momentum due to friction in the rope force will be same.
But not simultaneous.

Comment: @Sofia More to the point of the question, I think, is the assumption we have to make that the rope has mass.   Coils and elasticity are side issues.

Comment: It seems as if the two "lines" joining the rope are just lines to indicate where the points p1 and p2 are, and are not actually ropes. In that case F@P1=F@P2 assuming inelastic rope.

Comment: @putonymedio You said you are a "newbie". Don't be discouraged by the nastiness of some people on this site. Many of the people here are what I call "Sheldons" because they **seriously** lack social skills. Your question is a good, entry level question that can help many other people that are new to physics. Keep up the good work. I will gladly answer any homework question put on this site because there is no logic in allowing someone to flounder for hours on a problem that just isn't clicking for them. If you need to, just title any of them to me "Inquisitive" and, if I can, I'll answer.

Comment: Another thing to make clear is whether the system is in equilibrium or not. Is the rope tethered at its left hand end? @Inquisitive's answer is good for when the rope is being accelerated by the force, with no other forces (drag, tethering from other end) on the rope.

Answer (score 2):

They will experience a different force.

The rope and all parts of the rope are accelerating to the right at the same rate. If you slice the rope at $P_2$, there is a tension force that is accelerating that severed section to the right. That severed section has a mass that is less than the total mass of the rope, but the acceleration is the same, so the force at that point must be less than $F_1$.

The same reasoning applies at $P_1$. The force at that point is less than $P_2$.

All of this assumes that the density of the rope doesn't vary along the length of the rope in some fashion. The basic law/equation of concern in this situation is $F=ma$.